# Passing key/value object from AJAX POST to MVC 5 Controller action method coming as null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

After searching for a few hours here it is. I have an object full of key/value pairs of questionID's and answers. This is how survey.js's onCmplete method generates their question/answers when the survey is completed. The object that I wish to pass to the MVC controller looks like this:

```
{18: "No", 22: "windows 7", 23: "nc programming", 24: "Server"}
```

Here is my AJAX POST to my controller action method:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Assessment/CompleteAssessment',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: survey.data
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert('Success');
  })
  .fail(function(xhr) {
    alert('Failed.');
  });
```

On the back-end side, my action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CompleteAssessment(Dictionary<int, string> assessmentData)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

I put a breakpoint on the action method and it hits after I make the AJAX POST but I'm not getting any values passed into it. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Your object isn't [valid json.](http://jsonlint.com/) The id numbers need to be strings if you specify json. I'd start there with the debugging.

Comment: This also isn't a dictionary.  Start by building out a valid dictionary structure  first

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a parameter in your url link.  For example `"CompleteAssessment?assessmentData=" + whateverVariableYourePassingToController`